# How to convert a decimal to a integer number

Tags: groovy

In groovy if i have the code like this :

```
def num = 9
println mum/4
```

which outputs `2.25`. But what I want is whenever I get a decimal like this I need that number to rounded to next int number in our case it should be `3`. For example, if the result is `3.01` i need the output as `4`. Can anyone say me how to do this in groovy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the ceiling function.  I believe it is `Math.ceil`.

Comment: Beware that `Math.ceil` returns `double` and not `integer`.

Answer (score 3):

couple of other options; if you declare your var as:

```
def num = 9
int a = num / 4
println a
```

Or you can use integer division:

```
println num.intdiv( 4 )
```

Comment: I need to get `3` as output. In your example and it doesn't work, it returns only `2`...

Comment: @Ant's ahhh, the examples I gave will round down if less than a 0.5 increment.  That's the default for Java

Comment: Yes and I guess `Math.ceil` is the perfect for this situation :)